# Source code of a Google Search Result Page

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm a beginner at web scraping and was recently was introduced to some basics of the `requests` module and `selenium` for Python.

Using the `requests` module, I tried to download the source code of a simple webpage which comes up when you search up any arbitrary keyword on Google, let's say "Cats".
Here is the code for this:

```py
import requests

#The keyword I want to search Google For
search_keyword = "Cats" 

#Opening the URL using requests
page = requests.get(r"https://www.google.com/search?q"+search_keyword) 

#Break program if there is an error in opening previous link
page.raise_for_status() 

#obtain the source code for the Google Webpage as a String
source_code = page.text
```

Now, the problem that arises is, when I observe the string in the `source_code` variable, the Source Code In the String is very different from the source code I observe in Google Chrome with `Ctrl+U`. I've compared the two in detail and they are extensively different.

To elaborate, here is the last seven lines copied from the source code from   CHrome:

```html
}catch(e){_._DumpException(e)}
try{
var uj=function(a,b,c){_.Kd.log(46,{att:a,max:b,url:c})},wj=function(a,b,c){_.Kd.log(47,{att:a,max:b,url:c});a<b?vj(a+1,b):_.J.log(Error("aa`"+a+"`"+b),{url:c})},vj=function(a,b){if(xj){const d=_.ke("SCRIPT");d.async=!0;d.type="text/javascript";d.charset="UTF-8";var c=d;c.src=_.Ac(xj);_.tj(c);d.onload=_.be(uj,a,b,d.src);d.onerror=_.be(wj,a,b,d.src);_.Kd.log(45,{att:a,max:b,url:d.src});_.ee("HEAD")[0].appendChild(d)}},yj=class extends _.H{constructor(a){super(a)}},zj=_.F(_.Fd,yj,17)||new yj,Aj,xj=
(Aj=_.F(zj,_.ic,1))?_.qj(_.C(Aj,4)||""):null,Bj,Cj=(Bj=_.F(zj,_.ic,2))?_.qj(_.C(Bj,4)||""):null,Dj=function(){vj(1,2);if(Cj){const a=_.ke("LINK");a.setAttribute("type","text/css");_.pj(a,Cj,"stylesheet");let b=_.$c();b&&a.setAttribute("nonce",b);_.ee("HEAD")[0].appendChild(a)}};(function(){const a=_.Gd();if(_.E(a,18))Dj();else{const b=_.C(a,19)||0;window.addEventListener("load",()=>{window.setTimeout(Dj,b)})}})();
}catch(e){_._DumpException(e)}
})(this.gbar_);
// Google Inc.
;});})();(function(){google.drty&&google.drty(undefined,true);})();});</script><div></div><div jscontroller="MTV2Lb" style="display:none" src="/uviewer?q=cats&amp;origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com" id="Rvx4kc" jsaction="rcuQ6b:npT2md;u0pjoe:Hq0NGf"></div><div jscontroller="W0N1pf" id="DDeXhf" jsaction="u0pjoe:Hq0NGf"></div><div id="lfootercc"><script nonce="aZ5SspHCLpIp5NbwBB_sog">(function(){for(var i in google.iir||{}){_setImagesSrc([i],google.iir[i]);}google.iir={};})();(function(){var _jnu='https://www.google.com/ads/measurement/t';var _jnuid=2500;google.x({'id':'jnu'},function(){var bt = google.sx && google.sx.setTimeout || window.setTimeout;bt(function(){google.log('','',_jnu);},_jnuid);});})();google.jslm=3;</script><div id="reviewDialog" data-async-context="async_id_prefix:" data-jiis="up" data-async-type="reviewDialog" data-async-context-required="async_id_prefix" class="yp"></div><div id="dbg_"></div></div></body></html>
```

And here are the last seven lines of the string that is stored in `source_code`:

```html
else top.location='/doodles/';};})();</script><input value="AK50M_UAAAAAY717njRHtGFQobKw12k0KwtaX02a7bb3" name="iflsig" type="hidden"></span></span></td><td class="fl sblc" align="left" nowrap="" width="25%"><a href="/advanced_search?hl=en-PK&amp;authuser=0">Advanced search</a></td></tr></table><input id="gbv" name="gbv" type="hidden" value="1"><script nonce="t1EKgWOJQagENoMoyIq8zw">(function(){var a,b="1";if(document&&document.getElementById)if("undefined"!=typeof XMLHttpRequest)b="2";else if("undefined"!=typeof ActiveXObject){var c,d,e=["MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0","MSXML2.XMLHTTP","Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];for(c=0;d=e[c++];)try{new ActiveXObject(d),b="2"}catch(h){}}a=b;if("2"==a&&-1==location.search.indexOf("&gbv=2")){var f=google.gbvu,g=document.getElementById("gbv");g&&(g.value=a);f&&window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=f},0)};}).call(this);</script></form><div id="gac_scont"></div><div style="font-size:83%;min-height:3.5em"><br><div id="gws-output-pages-elements-homepage_additional_languages__als"><style>#gws-output-pages-elements-homepage_additional_languages__als{font-size:small;margin-bottom:24px}#SIvCob{color:#3c4043;display:inline-block;line-height:28px;}#SIvCob a{padding:0 3px;}.H6sW5{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px;white-space:nowrap}.z4hgWe{display:inline-block;margin:0 2px}</style><div id="SIvCob">Google offered in:  <a dir="rtl" href="https://www.google.com/setprefs?sig=0_r1jPgArqJ4B4gDPx-dpt_P_fF1c%3D&amp;hl=ur&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi7w86Hk738AhVwkZUCHQZ8Bm4Q2ZgBCAU">&#1575;&#1585;&#1583;&#1608;</a>    <a dir="rtl" href="https://www.google.com/setprefs?sig=0_r1jPgArqJ4B4gDPx-dpt_P_fF1c%3D&amp;hl=ps&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi7w86Hk738AhVwkZUCHQZ8Bm4Q2ZgBCAY">&#1662;&#1690;&#1578;&#1608;</a>    <a dir="rtl" href="https://www.google.com/setprefs?sig=0_r1jPgArqJ4B4gDPx-dpt_P_fF1c%3D&amp;hl=sd&amp;source=homepage&amp;sa=X&amp;ved=0ahUKEwi7w86Hk738AhVwkZUCHQZ8Bm4Q2ZgBCAc">&#1587;&#1606;&#1676;&#1610;</a>  </div></div></div><span id="footer"><div style="font-size:10pt"><div style="margin:19px auto;text-align:center" id="WqQANb"><a href="/intl/en/ads/">Advertising�Programs</a><a href="/intl/en/about.html">About Google</a><a href="https://www.google.com/setprefdomain?prefdom=PK&amp;prev=https://www.google.com.pk/&amp;sig=K_MVkcQYGVALpK2CEzShaNNS889C4%3D">Google.com.pk</a></div></div><p style="font-size:8pt;color:#70757a">&copy; 2023 - <a href="/intl/en/policies/privacy/">Privacy</a> - <a href="/intl/en/policies/terms/">Terms</a></p></span></center><script nonce="t1EKgWOJQagENoMoyIq8zw">(function(){window.google.cdo={height:757,width:1440};(function(){var a=window.innerWidth,b=window.innerHeight;if(!a||!b){var c=window.document,d="CSS1Compat"==c.compatMode?c.documentElement:c.body;a=d.clientWidth;b=d.clientHeight}a&&b&&(a!=google.cdo.width||b!=google.cdo.height)&&google.log("","","/client_204?&atyp=i&biw="+a+"&bih="+b+"&ei="+google.kEI);}).call(this);})();</script> <script nonce="t1EKgWOJQagENoMoyIq8zw">(function(){google.xjs={ck:'xjs.hp.L0TU2uVtv08.L.X.O',cs:'ACT90oHT93DEQlP6_b1H10Ysv5zFk8Lfjw',excm:[]};})();</script>  <script nonce="t1EKgWOJQagENoMoyIq8zw">(function(){var u='/xjs/_/js/k\x3dxjs.hp.en.O9Ix1H-6nJI.O/am\x3dAADoBABQAGAB/d\x3d1/ed\x3d1/rs\x3dACT90oE7kMfbiyrYlGzQlW0b_TuKFV-B6g/m\x3dsb_he,d';var amd=0;
var d=this||self,e=function(a){return a};var g;var l=function(a,b){this.g=b===h?a:""};l.prototype.toString=function(){return this.g+""};var h={};
function m(){var a=u;google.lx=function(){p(a);google.lx=function(){}};google.bx||google.lx()}
function p(a){google.timers&&google.timers.load&&google.tick&&google.tick("load","xjsls");var b=document;var c="SCRIPT";"application/xhtml+xml"===b.contentType&&(c=c.toLowerCase());c=b.createElement(c);a=null===a?"null":void 0===a?"undefined":a;if(void 0===g){b=null;var k=d.trustedTypes;if(k&&k.createPolicy){try{b=k.createPolicy("goog#html",{createHTML:e,createScript:e,createScriptURL:e})}catch(q){d.console&&d.console.error(q.message)}g=b}else g=b}a=(b=g)?b.createScriptURL(a):a;a=new l(a,h);c.src=
a instanceof l&&a.constructor===l?a.g:"type_error:TrustedResourceUrl";var f,n;(f=(a=null==(n=(f=(c.ownerDocument&&c.ownerDocument.defaultView||window).document).querySelector)?void 0:n.call(f,"script[nonce]"))?a.nonce||a.getAttribute("nonce")||"":"")&&c.setAttribute("nonce",f);document.body.appendChild(c);google.psa=!0};google.xjsu=u;setTimeout(function(){0<amd?google.caft(function(){return m()},amd):m()},0);})();function _DumpException(e){throw e;}
function _F_installCss(c){}
(function(){google.jl={blt:'none',chnk:0,dw:false,dwu:true,emtn:0,end:0,ico:false,ikb:0,ine:false,injs:'none',injt:0,injth:0,injv2:false,lls:'default',pdt:0,rep:0,snet:true,strt:0,ubm:false,uwp:true};})();(function(){var pmc='{\x22d\x22:{},\x22sb_he\x22:{\x22agen\x22:true,\x22cgen\x22:true,\x22client\x22:\x22heirloom-hp\x22,\x22dh\x22:true,\x22ds\x22:\x22\x22,\x22fl\x22:true,\x22host\x22:\x22google.com\x22,\x22jsonp\x22:true,\x22msgs\x22:{\x22cibl\x22:\x22Clear Search\x22,\x22dym\x22:\x22Did you mean:\x22,\x22lcky\x22:\x22I\\u0026#39;m Feeling Lucky\x22,\x22lml\x22:\x22Learn more\x22,\x22psrc\x22:\x22This search was removed from your \\u003Ca href\x3d\\\x22/history\\\x22\\u003EWeb History\\u003C/a\\u003E\x22,\x22psrl\x22:\x22Remove\x22,\x22sbit\x22:\x22Search by image\x22,\x22srch\x22:\x22Google Search\x22},\x22ovr\x22:{},\x22pq\x22:\x22\x22,\x22rfs\x22:[],\x22sbas\x22:\x220 3px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)\x22,\x22stok\x22:\x22xGs-7Ks6Q8q3RMls1jXZ4MoFStc\x22}}';google.pmc=JSON.parse(pmc);})();</script>        </body></html>
```

Is there a reason as to why there is this discrepancy? Does Google take measures to prevent downloading their proper source code or something? And how I can obtain the original source code for the webpage in Python.

Comment: Can you show parts of the different source codes? For example the first or last 20 lines of each?

Comment: Google will serve different responses depending on all sorts of things, not least whether you are logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your **user agent**, language, cookies and more. Requests usually use the `python-requests/*` user agent header, so you need to replace it with your browser's header
s. Copy these header values from your request to the network tab in devtools. I've also added an equals sign to the url.

```
import requests

#The keyword I want to search Google For
search_keyword = "Cats" 

url = r"https://www.google.com/search?q="+search_keyword # ADDED ?q=

# Copied from network tab in dev tools
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5026.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/103.0.1254.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"
}

#Opening the URL using requests
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 

#Break program if there is an error in opening previous link
page.raise_for_status() 

#obtain the source code for the Google Webpage as a String
source_code = page.text

with open("google1.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(source_code)
```

Comment: Works like a charm, interesting to know that the user-agent affects the source code this much. Thanks a lot Bud! Also, I'd appreciate if you could guide me in the right direction as to how I can copy the headers directly from Dev Tools.